# Объединение видео

Tags: android, java

Как можно объединить два видео в одно в android?

Есть нужда объединять несколько видео формата mp4, снятых на камеру телефона, простое объединение, второе видео будет являться продолжением первого видео.

Comment: FFMpeg. Остальное можно найти в гугле.

Comment: @supercreeper а есть что нибудь проще, мне достаточно простое объединение, а тут как я понял нужно столько манипуляций провести.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFMpeg - наше всё.

Мультиплатформенный инструмент для работы с медиафайлами, то есть не только с видео, но ещё и со звуком и изображениями!

Ребята из NetComps постарались и сделали очень простую библиотеку для работы с FFMpeg на Android. [Ссылка](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html).

Никакого геморроя с написанием своих велосипедов на С++, просто несколько строк на Java. Единственный минус - ARMv6 вроде как неполностью поддерживается, однако базовый функционал в виде объединения видео должен работать.

И ещё подниму тему оптимизации: не стоит склеивать VP9/HEVC видео длительностью 2-3 часа, ведь для этого потребуется очень много времени, если будете перекодировывать. Самый оптимальные условия: видео имеет одинаковый размер кадра и кодеки аудио/видео. Тогда можно очень быстро просто дописать содердимое второго файла к концу первого.

В других случаях используйте тактику [@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim):

> раскодировать, слить, закодировать назад.

Comment: > Тогда можно очень быстро просто дописать содердимое второго файла к концу первого.

это возможно только в некоторых, очень сильно ограниченных случаях. В 99.9% случаев этого делать нельзя.

Comment: @supercreeper как я понял, эта библиотека платная, а есть бесплатная версия?

Answer (score 2):

Просто так взять и объеденить нельзя. Так как файл с видео обычно заключен в контейнер, которые содержит заголовок и блоки с видео/аудио. А видео и аудио даже в двух очень похожих кусках видеофалов могут быть абсолютно разными и несовместимым. Также при кодировании видео современными кодеками практически не используется независимое кодирование кадров (разве что только MJPEG). Кадры зависят друг от дружки (к примеру, в mpeg4, (divx, xvid) это до 300 кадров в группе (что около 300/25 = 12 секунд).

Так что общий ответ - ffmpeg, раскодировать, слить, закодировать назад.